# How to select audio file URL with unique id using HTML5 & JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I want to make JavaScript HTML5 player, but I can't use common,
I have big data with mp3 files, each files have unique id, and I can't understand, how can I select the id and the put URL to player?

I just start learn JS, and can't figure out this

```
<audio controls>
 <source src="song.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio> 

//////==== DOM ====///////

<div id="23231">
 <a href="audio/song-1.mp3"></a>
 <button>play</button>
</div>
<div id="34561">
 <a href="audio/song-3.mp3"></>
 <button>play</button>
</div>
<div id="67771">
 <a href="audio/song-4.mp3"></a>
 <button>play</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this `$(this).parent().find('a').attr('href');` use with `class or tag` instead of `id`

```js
$(document).on('click','button',function(){
  var src = $(this).parent().find('a').attr('href');
  $('source').attr('src',src)
  console.log( $('source').attr('src'))
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<audio controls>
 <source src="song.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio> 

//////==== DOM ====///////

<div id="23231">
 <a href="audio/song-1.mp3"></a>
 <button>play</button>
</div>
<div id="34561">
 <a href="audio/song-3.mp3"></a>
 <button>play</button>
</div>
<div id="67771">
 <a href="audio/song-4.mp3"></a>
 <button>play</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add an `id` to the audio and the source element .

```
<audiod id="audioPlayer" controls>
 <source id="MP3source" src="song.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Plain Javascript

```
    var audio = document.getElementById('audioPlayer');

    var source = document.getElementById('MP3source');
    source.src= document.getElementById('23231')
               .getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href; 
    //set source.src to the link element inside the 23231 div

    audio.load(); //call this to just preload the audio without playing
    audio.play(); //call this to play the song right away
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code:

```js
function playmusic(file)
{

audio = file.parentNode.childNodes[1].getAttribute("href");
console.log(audio);
var obj = document.getElementById('player');
obj.src = audio;
obj.play();

}
```

```html
<audio id="player" controls>
 <source src="song.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio> 

//////==== DOM ====///////

<div id="23231">
 <a href="audio/song-1.mp3"></a>
 <button onClick="return playmusic(this)" >play</button>
</div>
<div id="34561">
 <a href="audio/song-3.mp3"></a>
 <button onClick="return playmusic(this)" >play</button>
</div>
<div id="67771">
 <a href="audio/song-4.mp3"></a>
 <button onClick="return playmusic(this)" >play</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I can't  ADD "value" like it, because "value" came from big data. I need add value from that data

Comment: then create a logic take the value from your data. How is ur big data look like

Comment: How is ur big data look like, It is look like DOM above

Comment: I have updated my answer with the same structure as your DOM. please have a look now

Comment: Thank you, It is work nicely. I have made it in codepen. http://codepen.io/when108/pen/bgmYPR